# How to redirect a folder?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following file location on my site `/businessplan/plan.php` and I would simply redirect it to `/plan` so when the user types `/plan` or `/plan/` it takes them to this location

Below is the start of my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: If you want, you can get this working without messing with htaccess at all, just by simply and plain html and javascript. Best luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the bottom of your .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/?plan/?$ /businessplan/plan.php [L]
```

`?` means 0 or 1 of the preceding pattern which, in the case above, is just the character `/`.  The 2nd `?` is so that the trailing `/` is optional.  The 1st `?` is so that the leading `/` is optional too.  URLs will or will not have the leading `/` depending if the rewrite rules are in .htacces or httpd.conf (or a child of it).  I can never remember which, so I always put the `^/?...` to cover both.

Comment: Would it work both ways, if someone types /businessplan/plan.php it rewrite the url to /plan and if someone writes /plan then it just grab the content from that page

Comment: Nope.  `/businessplan/plan.php` does not match any rewrite rule, so doesn't get changed.  Most folks will click on your `/plan` link, not type out the longer URL instead.